# Access to Derby database from html

Tags: html, database, derby

I am implementing a database backed login page, and its not clear to me how to connect Java code with my HTML page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that page is database backed

Comment: HTML doesn't directly connect to Derby. Java connects to Derby. You need a web server which supports something like Java Servlets (e.g., Tomcat), so that your HTTP request can be serviced by a servlet that can connect to Derby and then construct an HTML response.

Comment: Hi @user11001, please let me know whether my answer was use full for you(so i could update it if needed )?

Answer (score 0):

Generally implementation flow is next:

- You create [HTML form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) element with action which points to your java request handler.
- Within that java handler you have to perform login logic (connect to database, verify existence of user, password validity etc.)
- After verifying user credentials you can authenticate him by start new session for him.

See [User authentication and authorization embedded example](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/devguide/rdevcsecure26537.html)
  and [Creating a Java application to access a Derby database](https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/derby_app.html) to get actual working example with code snippets to connect to **derby** database.

Comment: Thanks, But how can i connect to database from html page?

Comment: you  connect to database from your java request handler.